# UserControl + ArrayList + vb.net

Tags: vb.net, user-controls

When i get the text of a listbox i write

```
ListBox1.Items(2).ToString()
```

What is the code that allows me to do this?

```
UserControl.positioniwant(2).title
UserControl.positioniwant(1).msg
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with an ArrayList. For that matter, you shouldn't use arraylists in .Net in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called an "Indexed Property":

```
Public Class Foo 

    Public Property Position(ByVal index As Integer) As String
        Get
            Return _position(index)
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            _position(index) = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _position(9) As String

End Class
```

Comment: Ok thank you... now i can put this "UserControl.Position(0)" but how i can put "UserControl.Position(0).Title = 'HI!!' " and get like that "msgbox(UserControl.Position(0).Title)"

Comment: I found this.. with your help and with this page my problem is solved. http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?609793-User-Control-Property-Group-Attributes